# Using HttpURLConnection to get Vimeo video file using token

Tags: java, android, video

I'm working on an android app that allows for local offline viewing of video content.

I'm trying to download a video from Vimeo using their API and I've run into an issue that I believe has to do with the url itself and it's authentication.

I am told that the URL is an HTTP 302 redirect.

I've tested my program with a popeye video from https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4 and it works correctly. But when I put in the Vimeo link, it fails to even connect.

This is the method that runs the actual connection.

```
public String DownloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedInputStream inStream = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        File FileDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);

        URL url = new URL(fileURL);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //Code stops here with vimeo video but not with popeye video.

        ...

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FileDir, fileName + ".mp4"));
        in = connection.getInputStream();
        inStream = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024 * 5);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 5];

        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

    } 
    ... //catch and finally { flush, close and disconnection}

    return null;
}
```

And this is the async task that sets the url and executes it.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     ...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {

//If it is a normal direct link such as site.com/video.mp4 (the popeye video)
//Set link to site.com/video.mp4 and save as "args[1]" on disk.

        if(FilenameUtils.isExtension(args[0], "mp4")){  
            DownloadFile(args[0], args[1]);             
        } 

//Else if a vimeo link (which it is)
        else if (args[0].contains("vimeo")){            
            final int pos = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);  

//Use Vimeo API to get the videos from Vimeo.                    
                VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(CHANNELS_VIDEO_URI, new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {

                @Override
                public void success(VideoList videoList) {

                    if (videoList != null && videoList.data != null && !videoList.data.isEmpty()) {
                        Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);

                        ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.files;
                        if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                            VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(0); 

//Set link to the link that you retrieve.
//Example: http://player.vimeo.com/external/175231540.hd.mp4?s=78206f99af10e32354851f6ca62252782b1393fb&profile_id=174&oauth2_token_id=903072961

                            String link = videoFile.link;
                            DownloadFile(link, args[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(VimeoError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failure in VideoList Reading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...

}
```

But the link http://player.vimeo.com/external/175231540.hd.mp4?s=78206f99af10e32354851f6ca62252782b1393fb&profile_id=174&oauth2_token_id=903072961 isn't being connected to. I tried removing everything after hd.mp4, but I assume this doesn't work because going to that link in a browser gets you an authorization denied error.

How can I connect to this link and get the file from the HTTP 302 redirect using the token?

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

I don't think you should assume the position passed in to doInBackground will be the same position after the network call to get a list of videos. What if a new video was added to that list?

What is `CHANNELS_VIDEO_URI`? Only Vimeo PRO members have access to the files array, and only for their own videos. This is mentioned in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#how-do-i-play-a-video) of the Vimeo networking library you are using. Is this a Channel of videos you own?

That URL in your comment looks incorrect, it represents the player and not a video file. Part of me doesn't believe that URL came from the `VideoFile.link`

The files array may also contain links other than mp4 files, so you should be wary of that as well.

There is a `download` array on each Video object. It is similar to `files`, except that these should be links to the actual video resource (and you won't get HLS!). These will only be available if the video's settings allow the video to be downloaded.

Comment: It does. That is the redirect HTTP I believe. It's what I'm getting directly from Log printouts in the code. I am a Pro member and yes, it is a channel I own. What I do is populate a channel in vimeo's client, then I pull that list of videos from the channel using vimeo's method and then access it's file array (which as you said requires Pro)

Comment: And yeah, it might be possible for an HLS (m3u8) file to be in the array, but I'll have to test for that separately. As for your point about a new video being added, that isn't a problem as the line that pulls the video(Video video = videoList.data.get(pos);) chooses based on the index of the grid view item selected. The error would occur only if there are more indexs in my grid view than videos in the vimeo channel. As long as I don't update my adapter with a listing that isn't existent in the channel, I won't pull an error. I can probably code for error handling with this as well.

Comment: These files are not meant to be downloaded, though. If you are looking for files that you can download, use the Video.download, which is an ArrayList of VideoFiles, similar to files, but are allowed to be downloaded (as specified in the video settings, but since you own these, you can mark them all as downloadable).

Comment: I updated my answer to highlight the download arraylist.

Comment: Sorry, this is something I let sit while I worked on other issues. I looked for the download arraylist that you claim is part of the video object, but I couldn't find it. I looked into the source code I had and I couldn't find it in Video.java. So I went to GitHub and found it in Video.java. I believe that this download object is from a recent commit that is not part of v1.0.1 but is currently available in v1.1.0. Should I download the github repo and try and add it as a submodule?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it wasn't in 1.0.1. Unfortunately 1.1.0 will break for you, as there is a dependency that we have yet to open source. That should happen within the next few weeks, at which time 1.1.0 will be pushed to jcenter.
For the time being, you could add it as a submodule using the master branch, and add the download member yourself - since it's a submodule you will have full access to the code and can make changes locally.